# Get new value in Fuelux Spinbox change event

Tags: javascript, fuelux

I'm using fuelux spinbox 3.7.3

According to the docs: http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#spinbox we can handle the change event through "changed.fu.spinbox". This event fires with two arguments: event and value, being value the current value.

Is it possible to get also the new value? (or at least know if it is an increase or a decrease). I examined both arguments and could find any reference to the new value.

At the time the event is fired, the input is still not updated and therefore I cannot get the new value that way..

In this change event I will take an action depending of it is an increment or a decrease.

Any other approach is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `changed.fu.spinbox` should return the new value.

I visited the [nightly build server for FUel UX](https://fuelux-dev.herokuapp.com/#spinbox) and if you open your browser's console, you should see that the change event returns the new value, not the old value. There is a bug that causes the changed event to fire twice on the first click of the spinbox, but after that the new value is returned via the `value` parameter of the event.

I would recommend storing the old value and comparing it with the new value in order to discover an increase or decrease.